# How to post like with ajax to instagram? Help me please

Tags: ajax, jquery, instagram

i have this code but its not working. it says to me ajax post is  success but when i look make refresh i saw its not liked.

```
<?
if ($data->user_has_liked == false) 
{ 
?>

<a href="#" id="<?=$data->id;?>" class="like"><span class="<?=$data->id;?>">Like</span></a>
<? } else { echo 'Liked'; } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
       $('a.like').click(function() {
            var mediaId = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/" + mediaId + "/likes?callback=?",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    access_token: '<?=$access_token;?>',
                    _method: 'POST'
                },
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  $("."+mediaId+"").text('Liked');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     $("."+mediaId+"").text('Error!<br/>' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
               }
             });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm having problems like this too. Would love to hear an answer. My post gets a 200 ok but nothing happens. In my case, I'm commenting.

Comment: i think we need to access_token for using website. try it.

Answer (score 2):

I am building something similar and have ran into this problem recently.

Even though your request is sent as a type: POST the request itself is actually sent as GET. This causes your request to return successful without liking anything. Instead it will return all the data for that Media ID.

If you change your datatype to JSON instead of JSONP you request should work as you wish; however, it may require an HTTPS connection requiring an SSL.